# Convert conditional algorithm to math

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need some help converting a function coded into math.

```
  function thresPred(A)
    if (A >0.1)
       P = 1
    else if (A <=0.1)
       P = 0
    end if

    return P
  end function
```

The input value A is based on the average of three sets of values. The code then assigns the value of A depending on the conditional statement.
I'm not sure if this would be appropriate:
\begin{equation}
a = f(p)
\begin{cases}
  1,& >=0.1; \\
  0,& <=0.1\; 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Is this correct? 
How do I introduce A as the average of three sets of values.

e.g. a = average of (1,0,1)

or

a = average(n1,n2,n3)
with the condition that n is always three values

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What in the world is that language?

Comment: it's just quick code, not based on any specific language. But I'm sure it's readable.

Comment: You have two open `if` but only one `end if`.

Comment: The `if (A <=0.1)` is also extraneous, as you already have `else`.

Comment: You also did not return `P`.

Comment: It is dummy code, not the actual code.

Comment: You still need to make sure that it is correct, or at least accurate.

Comment: Thank you @Kenny Lau I've updated the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58632/discussion-between-user2459813-and-kenny-lau).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For defining a:

$A = \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3} n_i$.

This is a compact way of saying $A=\frac{n_1+n_2+n_3}{3}$, which is the average. Note that $n$ is the number of elements in the set (what I think you meant was always three), $i$ is an index of a single element in that set, and $x_i$ is the element's value.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is correct, $n$ is always three.

Answer (score 0):

You reversed it. $A$ is the argument to your function. It should be:

$$P = f(A) = \begin{cases} 1 & A \ge 0.1 \\ 0 & A < 0.1 \end{cases}$$

I used $<$ instead of $\le$ because following the logic of your code, we would have $P=1$ if $A=0.1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand. I understand. How woud I go about introducing the A value as the average of three sets values.

Comment: Is that a separate question? Could you provide more context? Which three sets?

Comment: Thank you I'll update the question quickly. I really appreciate your help.